# Rails: Production assets loading from user's localhost instead of Ubuntu server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I just deployed my rails application to Ubuntu 16.04 Droplet. When the rails server is running from my local computer, I am able to view the website at myappname.com on the browser, but as soon as I shut down the rails server, the CSS fails.

Additionally, the CSS always fails for everyone else accessing it from a device that is not my local computer.

The issue here is that I've hard coded my site somewhere to try and retrieve files from the local computer of whoever visits the site and not the server itself. Per the error I'm seeing:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-ahsdjhkjads98ha98shd8ha98hds98hadskjhfo4h8fw9hhw398hhiuh9sd8h8hs89fdhj.css?body=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Because it says "localhost" there, everyone who tries to load that page will try to load it with something on their local computer. So it's actually my computer that's listening on port 3000 in this case, I'll need to adjust how my site is coded so that it's pulling those CSS assets from itself and not localhost.

In `config/environments/production.rb` I changed:

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

to:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Then on my Ubuntu server in my production environment I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, restarted the server with `sudo service apache2 restart`, but still could not solve the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've hardcoded, somewhere, `localhost:3000` in your code. Or your deploy did that for you. I'd start by doing a global search for `localhost:3000` in your code and see where it is. Additionaly, this can be caused by Rails or Puma, or even Apache' configs.

Comment: The only thing I found was this inside client_secret.json: `{"installed":{"client_id":"8934589754879453897-kjasdjhd898d98ahid9ha89cad.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"magnetic-clone-123133","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x520_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"KJHhhjhakddhas8yya87s7","redirect_uris":["lkslckncs;ncjnskdj;sndckj;","http://localhost.com"]}}`. I changed `localhost` to `pawbookings` in hopes this would be the fix but it was not.

Comment: Facing same issue here, http://localhost:3000/assets/gal-empty-ce6b150973b63aba43d62a61b1934e33eff840df0165da04b0b0839705a9b2dc.jpg on server

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `config.asset_host` in `config/application.rb` to your domain, but it sounds like your reverse proxy is misconfigured.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but this did not resolve the issue :/